# What font do you think it used in this image?

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to figure out what font this is in this image:

[image]

Do you think it's georgia or something else?

Answer (score 1):

While it is VERY close to Georgia, I don't believe it is.  What I always do, when trying to identify fonts, is type a few words out and go through my fonts, looking for distinguishing characteristics of each font.

I did this with the image that you supplied and picked up on a few differences right away.

**It's difficult to see in the shrunken image below, so I suggest you either right-click or control-click and view the image in a new tab.**

1. You can see below that the lowercase A in Georgia (top) is slightly
   different than the font below
2. You can also notice that the flat
   part of the lowercase E in Georgia is perfectly horizontal, but in
   the font you are trying to ID it slants upwards.
3. The bottom parts of
   the Ps also look a little different to me as well.

I'm sure the pattern would continue, if I had looked any further.

[image: differences]

That being said, I doubt anyone will actually notice a difference, so just use Georgia

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not Georgia. It's barely [Garamond Premier Pro](https://www.adobe.com/type/browser/landing/garamond/garamond.html). You can see it in the image below. The first part of image is the origina, second part is written by me on the original image and the third part is barely a text layer created by me. There is some differences about letter spacing but I think there will be no problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ is a great resource for identifying fonts from images. The other tool I use when WhatTheFont doesn't work is http://www.identifont.com/. The process is a little more tedious, but it all depends on how determined you are.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like, [Adobe® Caslon™ Regular](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFontPackage&code=1712&store=OLS-US&nr=0&newsample=non-profit&view=View) but it's hard to see from that screen grab. Look at the capital K and lowercase fi in profit for reference.